# PHP built-in webserver does not serve css or images when run from Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to build a simple PHP site.  In the run configuration I have the `Run as` property set to `PHP Built-in  Web Server (running on built-in web server)`.

When I run the project, the index.php file, and all the text in it loads, but no CSS styles, Javascript, or image files load correctly.  I get this error in the console regarding CSS:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/css/main.css".`

When I take a look at what has loaded in Chrome, I see that the css response was empty. The same goes for all the Javascript.

I tried just running it in the PHP webserver from the command line:

`php -S localhost:8001`

And this worked perfectly!  So I think the issue is related to some sort of Netbeans configuration.  I'm running it with the Chrome browser, and tried both with the "Netbeans Connector" on and off, to no avail.  If anybody knows what the issue might be, I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: Just tested it with the NB 8.1 RC2 - doesn't happen there. Which version do you use? And has your css file the [css icon](https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/73/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller/projects-win-css.png) in the project view?

Comment: Netbeans 8.0.2, and yes, it has the css icon.  Do you think its a bug in v 8.0?